# Translation of months and days in Calendar Views Module

Tags: views, datetime, i18n-l10n

The Views Calendar template displays months and days, i.e. June, July, Monday, Tuesday,  etc.

When someone changes from english to french, how can I tell it to display the months in a different language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to translate the strings. Go to Administration » Configuration » Regional and language » Translate interface, in the menu.

Then search for !month-name and !day-abbreviation and translate the strings to your language.

You can also download translations for the whole module on https://localize.drupal.org/translate/languages/fr

You can also use the [Localization update module](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update). From the UI of the module you can download and keep track of new translations for your downloaded modules.

Comment: And you can also use the [Localization update](https://www.drupal.org/project/l10n_update) module.